# Remove whole parent div if contained child div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have multiple divs with the class "et_pb_row_inner" that contain two columns each. Each of the columns contain a text container with the class "et_pb_text".

Here's the basic html:

```
<div class="et_pb_row_inner">
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text"></div></div>
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text"></div></div>
</div>

<div class="et_pb_row_inner">
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text"></div></div>
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text"></div></div>
</div>

<div class="et_pb_row_inner">
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text"></div></div>
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text"></div></div>
</div>
```

I need a way to check if the text in the second column of each row is empty and if so remove the whole row. Like so:

```
<div class="et_pb_row_inner">
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT</div></div>
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT</div></div>
</div>

<div class="et_pb_row_inner"> <!-- second column text empty, remove whole row -->
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT</div></div>
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">EMPTY</div></div>
</div>

<div class=".et_pb_row_inner"> <!-- second column text empty, remove whole row -->
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT</div></div>
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">EMPTY</div></div>
</div>
```

I found a code snippet and tried the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('.et_pb_row_inner').each(function() {
        if ($('.et_pb_text', this).text() == "" ) {
            $('.et_pb_row_inner').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

It kind of works, but it removes ALL divs with the class "et_pb_row_inner", not just the ones that contain the empty text div.

I guess it's just tweaking the code a little, but I can't get it working.

Any ideas?

Comment: look at `parentElement` in JavaScript. That way you can do `$('.et_pb_text', this).parentElement.remove()`

Comment: That's pretty close, thank you! But it just removes the column which is the direct parent to the text div. However I need to remove the row. Is there a way to adress the parent of the parent?

Comment: you can do `parentElement.parentElement.remove()` but this type of operation is not recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your HTML third row, you mistakenly added "." in class name

Now below snippet will get the job done

```js
$(function() {
   $('.et_pb_row_inner').each(function(_, item) {    
        let text = $(item).children().eq(1).text();
      if(text.trim() === "EMPTY"){
        $(item).remove();    
      }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="et_pb_row_inner">
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT1</div></div>
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT</div></div>
</div>

<div class="et_pb_row_inner"> <!-- second column text empty, remove whole row -->
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT2</div></div>
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">EMPTY</div></div>
</div>

<div class="et_pb_row_inner"> <!-- second column text empty, remove whole row -->
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT3</div></div>
   <div class="et_pb_column"><div class="et_pb_text">EMPTY</div></div>
</div>
```

**Edited:**

Replaced the `$(item).empty()` with `$(item).remove()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's pretty close, however this code just removes the content of the div "et_pb_row_inner", but not the div itself.

Comment: Just replace empty with remove and you are good to go

Comment: Great, that was it! Works like a charm! Thanks for your help. Just for the record: In line 3 I removed the EMPTY between the "" to check for the empty divs.

Comment: :),  Do upvote the answer. if it is useful, as for new contributors it gives motivation :)

Comment: I tried, but the error message says I need at least 15 reputation to upvote :$

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the _inner div using the Child Nodes of the div with no text. You can run the _inner class selector on these with the .find function on the parent div.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $('.et_pb_row_inner').each(function() => {
        if ($('.et_pb_text', this).text() == "") {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

`this` should point to the `.et_pb_row_inner` currently in iteration

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.et_pb_row_inner').each((idx, ele) => {
    if($($(ele).children()[1]).text() === ''){
        $(ele).hide();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:contains` selector to achieve what you require in a single line of code. The caveat here is that it's a greedy match, ie. in this case it would also match 'NOT EMPTY'. I'll leave that as a matter for the OP to determine if this fits their use case.

```js
$('.et_pb_row_inner:contains("EMPTY")').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_row_inner">
  <div class="et_pb_column">
    <div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_column">
    <div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="et_pb_row_inner">
  <div class="et_pb_column">
    <div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_column">
    <div class="et_pb_text">EMPTY</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="et_pb_row_inner">
  <div class="et_pb_column">
    <div class="et_pb_text">HAS TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_column">
    <div class="et_pb_text">EMPTY</div>
  </div>
</div>
```